# Unable to access cells from CollectionView element in UITest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to access cells from CollectionView element in UITest. Unlike tableview I could be able to get cells only that are visible even if I scrolled to the end of the collection view. Just I want to know is it possible in any way to access all cells from collectionview like we access from tableview element.

Actually my requirement is to check the number of cells should be displayed less than 10 even if the mocked response has more.

I have put additional effort to understand more about collection view and its caching strategy. 
 However there are lot of experts here could answer in simple way in no time. Hence I am posting this. Your answer may help to someone like me who struggles to access the cells from collectionview.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I have mock server implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CollectionView does not expose off-screen subviews – probably to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have a doubt here collection view will not expose off-screen element or the element will not be created until it is about to come into visible area?

Comment: The off-screen elements of the collection view do not exist until they are needed. 
They also disappear once they become off-screen.